# Problem with a closed epigraph function

Tags: analysis

Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function with closed epigraph
$$
E=\{(x,y) \in X \times \mathbb R: y \geq f(x) \},
$$
defined on a metric space $X$. Is it then possible to find a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ and $x\in X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $f(x_n) \rightarrow -\infty$ ?

Comment: Are you sure you've said what you meant? I ask because, as stated, the question admits lots of counterexamples. You could take $X$ to consist of one point and $f$ to be any map you like from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. More generally, you could take any metric space $X$ and any continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: I think that there is no such sequences but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there won't be any such sequence. To prove it, suppose $(x_n)$ were such a sequence with limit $x$, and consider the sequence of points $P_n=(x_n,y_n)$ where $y_n$ is defined to be the larger of $f(x_n)$ and $f(x)-1$. Because $y_n\geq f(x_n)$, all these points $P_n$ are in $E$.  Furthermore, once $n$ is large enough, we'll have $f(x)-1>f(x_n)$ (because $f(x_n)\to-\infty$), and so $P_n=(x_n,f(x)-1)$.  So the sequence of points $P_n$ converges to $(x,f(x)-1)$, which is not in $E$.  That contradicts the assumption that $E$ is closed.